# Blank white page on GitHub Page. Console has error "Failed to Load Module Script"

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages, web-development-server

The specific error that I am getting is:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

The page is supposed to be hosted on https://manthewell.github.io/
The repository is at https://github.com/ManTheWell/manthewell.github.io

I've been looking for a solution but have been unable to find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried adding lines found from other online sources to no effect, as well as making sure that the page is pointed to the right folder (it is pointed to /docs), and even tried renaming a .js file to .mjs in order to get that to work, but to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

`Main.tsx` appears to be a React source file, which the server is correctly identifying as an octet stream. Anyway, the file will need to be transpiled into JavaScript before the browser will have any idea what to do with it; React is not supported in the browser.